# Filtering cosine similarity scores into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to calculate cosine similarity scores between all possible combinations of text documents from a corpus. I'm using scikit-learn's `cosine_similarity` function to do this. Since my corpus is huge (30 million documents), the number of possible combinations between the documents in the corpus is just too many to store as a dataframe. So, I'd like to filter the similarity scores using a threshold, as they're being created, before storing them in a dataframe for future use. While I do that, I also want to assign the corresponding IDs of each of these documents to the index and column names of the dataframe. So, for a data value in the dataframe, each value should have index(row) and column names which are the document IDs for which the value is a cosine similarity score.

```
similarity_values = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix), index = IDs, columns= IDs)
```

This piece of code works well without the filtering part. `IDs` is a list variable that has all document IDs sorted corresponding to the tfidf matrix.

```
similarity_values = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix)>0.65, index = IDs, columns= IDs)
```

This modification helps with the filtering but the similarity scores are turned into boolean (True/False) values. How can I keep the actual cosine similarity scores here instead of the boolean True/False values.

Comment: cosine_similarity will output a square matrix and in that it may be possible that in a single column one value is >0.65 and others are less. So in that case, how will you want the column be appearing in the dataframe?

Comment: @VivekKumar Good question. I want the dataframe to have all values stacked on top of each other. i.e. each row in the dataframe should have only one similarity score and the corresponding document IDs. `similarity_values = similarity_values.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'ID1','level_1':'ID2', 0:'Score'})`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is breaking down the cosine similarity to batches. For example, you're using `cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix)` to generate an NxN matrix, but you can also use `cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[:5], tfidf_matrix)` to generate a 5xN matrix. In this case we can do the following based on your followup clarification:

```
# source: followup clarification #2 
def question_followup_transformer(df):
  return df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'ID1','level_1':'ID2', 0:'Score'})
```

```
# Copyright 2024 Google LLC.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# corpus is not provided in the example. 
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

matrix_length = tfidf_matrix.shape[0]

BATCH_SIZE = 10
FILTER_THRESHOLD = 0.6

df = []
# we iterate (matrix_length//batch_size) times.
for i in range(0, matrix_length - BATCH_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE):
  # compute cosine similarity for a subMatrix.
  subMatrix = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[i:i+BATCH_SIZE], tfidf_matrix)

  # set the proper index of the submatrix in a dataframe.
  similarity_values = pd.DataFrame(
      subMatrix, 
      index = range(i, i+BATCH_SIZE), 
      columns= range(0, matrix_length))
  
  # apply the stack transformation from the followup clarification.
  stacked_df = question_followup_transformer(similarity_values)

  # filter all scores below the the filter threshold.
  filtered_df = stacked_df.query("Score > {}".format(FILTER_THRESHOLD))

  # append dataframe to a list.
  df.append(filtered_df)

# concat all dataframes to a single one. 
df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```